# change submit in to onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, google-api, onkeyup

I have found a nice script at [Google Powered Site Search](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/09/google-powered-site-search-ajax-jquery/)  I'm trying to change the jquery with no luck so far.

I changed this code:

```
$(‘#searchForm’).submit(function(){
googleSearch();
return false;
});
```

In to this:

```
$(‘#s’).keyup(function() {
$(‘#searchForm’).submit(function(){
googleSearch();
return false;
});
```

But it doesn’t work…Can someone tell me way that is.??

I also tried this:

```
$(“input”).keyup(function () {
googleSearch();
return false;
});
```

Also didn’t work. It’s just jquery so it should work..

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Do the original code is working? Also the modified code have missing end braces.

Check this:

```
    $('#s').keyup(function() {
        $('#searchForm').submit(function(){
        googleSearch();
        return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. At this moment I'm not able to acces my files(my internet is down). So I can't look at it yet.

Comment: Hi, something strange is happening...I downloaded the files at the given url on to my desktop but the web-search isn't working. Can someone tell me why that is. (I think the web-search is deprecated and now it absolutely needs an API-Key but I'm not sure because it is working online in the demo of the given url. Does that mean it only works online..???)

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem. There could be some settings need to change in connecting to web-search. Or could it be something blocking your connection to it or maybe your conclusion also correct. Check the response of your request with firebug or chrome developer-tools to know if there's an error. You can also post new question if this case is different.

Comment: I'm using a computer at work. It could be the connection(firewall,server related). I'm just going to assume that's the case and than try it later from my home-computer. Unfortunately my internet is still down so that is going to take a while..(In the mean time I'm going to alter the page with (css,js) with the news-image search because those are functioning good). Thanks for your input:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works :

```
$("#s").keyup(function(){
     googleSearch();
     return false;         
 })
```

See [Eg](http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/aTzQV/3/)

Comment: Thank you. At this moment I'm not able to acces my files(my internet is down). So I can't look at it yet.

Comment: Hi, something strange is happening...I downloaded the files at the given url on to my desktop but the web-search isn't working. Can someone tell me why that is. (I think the web-search is deprecated and now it absolutely needs an API-Key but I'm not sure because it is working online in the demo of the given url. Does that mean it only works online..???)

Comment: Hi, the jquery is online: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js